# Is there a way to impersonate a View?

Tags: swift, uiview

I have just a quick question:

Is there a way to impersonate a View? I have designed a View in Storyboard.
But now I want to use many Views which are exactly the same as the one designed in Storyboard. I basically just want to "copy" the view 7 times.
I`ve tried

```
let testarray:[UIView] = [someview, someview, someview]
```

But then of course if I change the values of one view it changes the value of all views and thats not what I wont.
I hope you understand what I want to do because my english skills are not that brilliant.

Comment: You can create an xib and create as many instance you want programatically or you can use collectionview/tableview

Comment: I`ve tried to do this with a xib file. But in the View I want to copy is a tableview and I could not manage it to have a tableview in a xib file. Is this possible?

Comment: can you show the outcome that you want like design.. your question is not clear. you can create a tableview cell in xib and you can use the same xib in as many tableviews you want. tableview or collectoinview are build to effectively repeat cells.

Comment: It's possible. Create a weak @IBOutlet reference to the `UIView` in your codebase and do what you want with it.

Comment: I want to "copy" a view which contains a table view. And i could not manage it to add a hole table view width dynamic prototypes to a xib file. So i tried it in the normal interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, using Xibs. The way I personally do it is the following

1. I create a `.xib` file with one view inside, let's say `MyView.xib`
2. Create a `.swift` file with your class inside, `MyView.swift`. Inside this put all the `@IBOutlet` and everything.
3. Inside `MyView.xib`, add `MyView` as owner of the xib and links the outlets to the subviews
4. Make sure your class `MyView` extends the following class `CustomXibView` that you can add to your project (this is the one I use in my project)

   ```
   @IBDesignable
   class CustomXibView: UIView {

       @objc internal var defaultXib: String {
           return String(describing: type(of: self))
       }

       override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           loadXib(xib: defaultXib)
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           loadXib(xib: defaultXib)
       }

       private func loadXib(xib: String) {

           // Load view
           let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
           let nib = UINib(nibName: xib, bundle: bundle)
           let contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

           // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
           contentView.frame = bounds

           // Make the view stretch with containing view
           contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]

           // Make sure layout uses superview margins
           preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true

           // Adding custom subview on top of our view
           addSubview(contentView)
       }
   }
   ```

   5. If you want to create your view, just initialize it with `MyView()`

Comment: But can I have a tableview inside the xib? At first I also had a xib but because of this problem I switched to storyboard.

Comment: Yes you can have any kind of view.

Comment: The only thing is, by default the xib file will contain one `UIView`. If you want your view to be something more specific (i.e. `UITableView` or `UITableViewCell` or anything), you can just delete the view and then drag a tableView. By default the code I shared will use the first view object in the xib file.

Comment: I did not really understand your explanation. But I think this is because of my bad english and bad programming skills. I`ve understand it like in this scheme: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmkehtmrpdm9815/explanation%20stack%20overflow.jpg?dl=0 
Did I understand it right respectively where I have to write which code? And how I implement the tableview in the xib file?

Comment: Do you have for example a link to a tutorial where this is explained. I did not find any tutorial where a tableview is implemented in a xib file.